# How to declare a long string in Python?

Tags: python

I have a really long string in python:

```
long_string = '
this is a really
really
really
long
string
'
```

However, since the string spans multiple lines, python doesn't recognize this as a string. How do I fix this?

Comment: Put it in `"""..."""`. `"""long-long-string"""`

Comment: Aren't triple quotes reserved for doc strings?

Comment: @ffledgling it's reserved for multiline strings, which are used for doc strings

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
long_string = '''
this is a really
really
really
long
string
'''
```

`"""` does the same thing.

Comment: In cases where indenting the string's lines makes the code more readable, you can use `dedent` to remove the indentation in the resulting string.

Comment: For me this is adding \n \n characters into the string when printed.  How would I avoid this ??

Comment: @blissweb Add `.replace("\n", " ")` on the end.

Answer (score 120):

You can also do this, which is nice because you have better control over the whitespace inside of the string:

```
long_string = (
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, '
    'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna '
    'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation '
    'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. '
    'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit '
    'esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint '
    'occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia '
    'deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
)
```

Comment: Indeed, this is one of the things that I ran into when I wanted to create a tuple with one element ;)

Comment: This appears to not work the moment you need any evaluated value that isn't a string. Typically for me, when using list comprehension to implode complex data into a string; and I have not found a way to combine such an expression with this string definition style. :(

Comment: You can also use long_string = textwrap.dedent('''long string with each line indented''') https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent

Comment: FYI: This is the preferred way of declaring a [long string in multiple lines.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and the accepted answer will introduce next line characters(which are not always needed.)

Answer (score 27):

You can use either

```
long_string = 'fooo' \
'this is really long' \
'string'
```

or if you need linebreaks

```
long_string_that_has_linebreaks = '''foo
this is really long
'''
```

Comment: Also, for your first option if you have parentheses round the string you don't need the backslashes. However notice the big drawback with using string concatenation: unless you are really careful about spaces you could end up with `"fooothis is really longstring"` which probably wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

I was also able to make it work like this.

```
long_string = '\
this is a really \
really \
really \
long \
string\
'
```

I can't find any online references to this way of constructing a multi-line string. I don't know if it's correct. My suspicion is that python is ignoring the newline because of the backslash? Maybe someone can shed light on this.

Comment: Also, Sublime Text (Build 3114) seems to have trouble with syntax highlighting this.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a comment but indentation does not seem to work in comments.

In the code below I show how the answer by @ShunYu. , which seems quick to type, compares with the solution by @Superstring in the context of a function definition:

```
def test() :


    string1='\
The city was bustling with activity as \
people hurried to and fro, going about \
their daily routines.\
\n\
Cars honked their horns, buses roared down the streets, and the air was filled with the sound of chatter and laughter.\
'

    string2=(
    'The city was bustling with activity as '
    'people hurried to and fro, going about '
    'their daily routines.'
    '\n'
    'Cars honked their horns, buses roared down the streets, and the air was filled with the sound of chatter and laughter.'
    )
    print(string1)
    print('\n')
    print(string2)
```

**Output:**

> The city was bustling with activity as people hurried to and fro,
> going about their daily routines. Cars honked their horns, buses
> roared down the streets, and the air was filled with the sound of
> chatter and laughter.
>
> The city was bustling with activity as people hurried to and fro,
> going about their daily routines. Cars honked their horns, buses
> roared down the streets, and the air was filled with the sound of
> chatter and laughter.

The answer provided by @SuperString allows the string to be indented inside a function whereas the answer by @ShunYu. seems to require removing the indentation..